# LinkedList Queue to List of Integers Method C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two classes that represent a linked list implementation of a queue. Ultimately, I want to be able to bind an object of the queue to a list (to be able to bind it to a gird view).

However, trying to use foreach in methods will not work as 'Queue does not have a public definition for GetEnumerator'.

I need a method in the base class (queue) that will return all the node's data items in their order in the form of an array/list.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public class Queue
{
    private Node Head;
    private Node Tail;
    private int Count = 0;
    public Queue() { }
    public void Enqueue(int OrderID)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(OrderID);
        if (Head == null)
        {
            Head = newNode;
            Tail = Head;
        }
        else
        {
            Tail.Next = newNode;
            Tail = Tail.Next;
        }
        Count++;
    }
    public int Dequeue()
    {
        if (Head == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Nothing in queue.");
        }
        int Result = Head.OrderID;
        Head = Head.Next;
        return Result;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return Count;
    }

}


public class Node
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public Node Next { get; set; }
    public Node(int ID)
    {
        this.OrderID = ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a question here. What's your *specific* question?

Comment: How would you change the methods in the classes for it to be compatible with binding to gridviews?

Comment: Note: I recommend trying to avoid class names that match existing framework classes.  Although they can be disambiguated using namespaces, it is still disruptive, both when writing code (annoying) and reading code (not always completely obvious that the type is not a framework type).

Comment: @Brian: Oh my goodness yes. Please don't name things `List`, and so on. I once spent the better part of an hour trying to debug a user's program that was behaving bizarrely when I discovered that they had written their own slightly different interface called `IEnumerable<T>`. If it hurts when you do that, then *don't do that*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create recursive method to perform it.

```
    public List<Node> GetAllNodes()
    {
        var allNodes = new List<Node>();
        GetAllNodesRecursive(allNodes, Head);
        return allNodes;
    }

    private void GetAllNodesRecursive(List<Node> allNodes, Node node)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        allNodes.Add(node);
        GetAllNodesRecursive(allNodes, node.Next);
    }
```

**Usage**

```
        var queue = new Queue();
        queue.Enqueue(1);
        queue.Enqueue(2);
        queue.Enqueue(4);
        var nodeList = queue.GetAllNodes();
```

To retrieve list of `OrderId` integers;

```
var orderIDList = queue.GetAllNodes().Select(x => x.OrderId).ToList();
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with calling the Head in the getAllNodes method as its not defined in the current context.

Comment: Did you defined these methods inside Queue class ?

Comment: I amended my code and this error no longer comes up, is there a way of converting this list of nodes into a list of integers so that I can bind it to a grid view?

Answer (score 2):

You can just implement *IEnumerable* interface:

```
public class Queue<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private Node _head;
    private Node _tail;
    private int _count = 0;
    public void Enqueue(T value)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(value);
        if (_head == null)
        {
            _head = newNode;
            _tail = _head;
        }
        else
        {
            _tail.Next = newNode;
            _tail = _tail.Next;
        }
        _count++;
    }
    public T Dequeue()
    {
        if (_head == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Nothing in queue.");
        }
        var result = _head.Value;
        _head = _head.Next;
        _count--;
        return result;
    }

    public int GetCount()
    {
        return _count;
    }

    private class Node
    {
        public readonly T Value;
        public Node Next { get; set; }
        public Node(T value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var iter = _head;
        while (iter != null)
        {
            yield return iter.Value;
            iter = _head.Next;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then in code:

```
var queue = new Queue<int>();
queue.Enqueue(1);
queue.Enqueue(100);

foreach(var item in queue)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

PS: Also, fixed you error with GetCount() method on Dequeue.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, there seems to be some problem with the interface definition, where it says 'IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()', an error occurs reference "Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>' requires 1 type arguments."

Comment: Type usings on top of your file: using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: Hello again, the queue seems to be able to add the required data items correctly, but databinding runs into a out of memory exception: 'An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code'